# Translate Active Admin default_actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have set up Active Admin with french translation. Everything works fine, except the form actions, which are not translated.

For example, I get `Update model` instead of `Mettre à jour`.

Is it supposed to be in the french translation file (`fr.yaml`)?

**UPDATE**

I managed to translate the create action with the following yml from formtastic's locale file:

```
fr:
  formtastic:
    yes: 'Oui'
    no: 'Non'
    create: 'Créer'
    update: 'Modifier'
    submit: 'Envoyer'
    cancel: 'Annuler'
    reset: 'Réinitialiser'
    required: 'requis'
```

However, the  `Update` action does not get translated...

**UPDATE 2**

I changed `f.actions` to

```
f.actions do
  f.action :submit
  f.action :cancel
end
```

And the submit now gets translated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Admin uses Formtastic gem. Try to change formtastic locale.

Example:

```
fr:
  formtastic:
    titles:
      post_details: "Post details"
    labels:
      post:
        title: "Your Title"
        body: "Write something..."
        edit:
          title: "Edit title"
    hints:
      post:
        title: "Choose a good title for your post."
        body: "Write something inspiring here."
    placeholders:
      post:
        title: "Title your post"
        slug: "Leave blank for an automatically generated slug"
      user:
        email: "you@yours.com"
    actions:
      create: "Create my %{model}"
      update: "Save changes"
      reset: "Reset form"
      cancel: "Cancel and go back"
      dummie: "Launch!"
```

[Formtastic I18n Guide](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#enhanced-localization-formtastic-i18n-api)

Comment: I didn't think about that! It must be the solution. I will try tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Your yml did not work, but I found a locale file inside the github repository. I updated my question.

Comment: It turned out active admin installed formtastic 2.2.1. I specified formtastic 4 in my gemfle and it worked.